# API Json to Object in angular 2

Tags: json, api, angular, object, typescript

I have a Json API with a structure such as

```
`{
    "type":"champion",
    "version":"7.8.1",
    "data":
     {
       "Jax":
       { 
            "id":24,
            "key":"Jax",
            "name":"Jax",
            "title":"o Grão-Mestre das Armas",
            "image":
            {
                  "full":"Jax.png",
                  "sprite":"champion1.png",
                  "group":"champion",
                  "x":144,
                  "y":48,
                  "w":48,
                  "h":48
              }
         }
......`

And I need to tranform this in a Object
My classes for this are this:

`export class Champion{
    private type: string;
    private version: string;
    private data: MasterModel[];
    from(data: any): Champion {
        this.type = data.type;
        this.version = data.version;
        this.data = data.data;
        return this;
    }
}`
```

https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/static-data/v3/champions?champData=image&api_key=RGAPI-2e393a98-cc36-4e17-b94b-e19622d1573a

```
`export class MasterModel{
    private master: ChampionDto;
    from(data: any): MasterModel {
        this.master = data.data;
        return this;
    }
}`

`export class ChampionDto{
    constructor(public id: number, public key: string, public name: string, public title: string, public image : ChampionImg){}
    from (data: any): ChampionDto {
        this.id = data.data.master.id;
        this.key = data.data.master.key;
        this.name = data.data.master.name;
        this.title = data.data.master.title;
        this.image = data.data.master.image;
     return this;
    }
}`

`export class ChampionImg{ 
    constructor(public full: string, public sprite: string, public group: string, public x: number, public y: number, public w: number, public h: number){}
    from (data: any): ChampionImg {
        this.full = data.full;
        this.sprite = data.sprite;
        this.group = data.group;
        this.x = data.x;
        this.y = data.y;
        this.w = data.w;
        this.h = data.h;
        return this;
    }
}`
```

That is correctly ? what is te best way to get this data to put in my object ? 
I was doing

--Service

```
`getChampion(): Observable<Champion> {
        return this._http.get(this.riotUrl)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .map(res => new Champion().from(res))
            .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
    }`
```

--Component

```
`getData() {
    this._ChampionService.getChampion()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.champions = data;
      })
  }`
```

But doens't work 
idk if help, but i want to do something like this -> http://gameinfo.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/game-info/champions/

Someone help me ? Thankkkks

Comment: I do not believe duck typing should require you to map data from a call to an object as long as their structure is identical. What happens if you get rid of the `map(res => new Champion().from(res))` line?

Comment: Nothing happens :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you actually use interfaces. Since you know the model of your data, you can just type them to interfaces. In this example I have restructured you JSON to the following format:

```
{
  type: "champion",
  version: "7.8.1",
  champions: [
    {
      // each champion details here
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `champion` is an Object, which contains an array of all champions. If you want to build this differently, you can make the appropriate changes to the code.

Service code simply mapping like so:

```
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
```

The real magic happens in the component :P

```
  .subscribe(data => {
    // add the type and version and empty array of champions        
    this.champion = {type:data.type,version:data.version,champions:[]}      
    let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(data.data),
    keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
        // push values of each champion to the array
        this.champion.champions.push(data.data[key]);
    });
  })
```

Now you have a nice little object with an array of champions, upon which you can do your magic :)

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sUsuxauzGVyImQnEIXkO?p=preview)

I have not completely made the interfaces, but I recommend you do it :)

Hope this helps or at least nudges you in the right direction :)

Comment: Hopefully this is something you are looking for. If we need to tweak something let me know :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear! :) :)